# How to get Z Euler Rotation value of constrained object?

Tags: shaders, constraints, drivers

[image: GIF of the problem. The empty copies the rotation of the head bone through a Child Of constraint]

I have a shader that uses the Z rotation of an empty (called Sara_Origin) through drivers to calculate the shadows on the face. The empty's rotation is constrained to the head bone of the character using a Child Of constraint.

The problem is when rotating the head bone, the empty's rotation doesn't update since it's using a Child Of constraint. Rotating the empty itself works fine.

Is there a way to find the Z Euler rotation value of the empty after it has been rotated through the constraint?

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GHTdupXcntijcWMuGX7ZYcwEthAoiqMR/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Here's my Driver setup]

Comment: Would be nice if you could link the blend file with materials again, so that others can better understand the scene and learn from it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to find the Z Euler rotation value of the empty after it has been rotated through the constraint?

Yes.

There are two different ways to get an object's transform into a driver:

[image]

One way gets the raw f-curve data, by driving from a "single property", set to the appropriate path.  This gets the number that you see in your transform fields when selecting the object.  It takes into account f-curves, f-curve modifiers, and drivers.  It does not take constraints into account.  It is always in the local space of the target.

The second way is to drive from a "transform channel" in the driver.  This is the value after any constraints have been applied.  It is also remapped from what you might expect your raw values to be: rotations will be remapped to the -180, 180 range and Euler angles will be anti-aliased into whatever method Blender uses (like a 180,0,180 XYZ is going to be read as a 0,180,0 Euler.)

Both methods are useful.  For people making rotating gear ratios, they need raw values.  For you, you need the values after constraints, so use the second kind.

Comment: Thanks! This and the other answer work perfectly, thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean now:

You want to influence the light/shadows with the angle of the sun and additionally with a gizmo, but at the same time include the rotation of the head, right?

[image]

If I'm right, then you would actually only have to additionally capture the rotation of the head.

You can solve it this way or something similar:

[image]

I just created an additional driver here that captures the rotation of the head.

But since the orientation is different here, you use the X-axis instead of the Z-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to pack the files. Updated the link, should have the materials now. And the method above doesn't work, I need the rotation value of the constrained empty, any ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer and the other one here both work perfectly ^^